# How to give SUPER privileges to remote user in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database in the server. I'd like to insert some data that I have in .csv format. After connecting to remote database, I try to execute below SQL statement.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/Downloads/words.csv'
INTO TABLE word
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Result is the error:

> The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

After doing some research, I understood that I have to enable **local-infile** to be able import csv to table. In order to set **local-infile** to **1** I execute this statement:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;
```

Result is the error:

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the
>   SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

And when I try to grant all permissions to remote user with below statement

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO username@host;
```

I get,

> You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

even to I'm logged in as root. What do I need to do?

Comment: If the remote user didn't already exist, how were they able to connect to the DB and try to execute the `LOAD DATA` command?

Answer (score 0):

Create the user before giving it a grant;

```
CREATE USER username@host IDENTIFIED BY 'some password'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO username@host;
```

Comment: I wonder how the user was able to execute the first query and get a permissions error if the user didn't exist.

Comment: Remote user already exists. I can execute SELECT, INSERT statements when I log in as remote user.